# Pull Request status check on unmerged branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to change one of the status checks on our pull requests to run on the unmerged version of the branch we are trying to merge in rather than the resulting merge branch, but I am not sure how to do this or if it is possible.

The status check is some GUI tests in a old style release pipeline however I am hoping to change this to a YAML pipeline shortly. It is simply running some powershell and then some VS tests.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this? Note the source branch could theoretically be entirely different than the target (e.g. coming off of a very old commit.) One thing you may be able to do is to run the pipeline against your source branch directly.

Comment: Aware it is a strange thing to do. Unfortunately decision is outside my control. The TL;DR is that the tests are not fast or reliable and using the current method any change to master resets this check and is causing a bottleneck. Solution decided upon is to run the test on the unmerged version of the branch and to then also run the tests on the master branch each night to ensure this hasnt regressed.

Comment: "Pull requests" don't exist in Git (they're not a base Git feature), so how you replace the commit(s) in some PR depends on whose add-on PR system you're using. In this case that's apparently azure-pipelines. I only know the answer for GitHub, which may not be the same.